# Heroku, Rails, & Devise: Splitting Traffic Between Two Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have two apps setup on myapp.com and beta.myapp.com. Both have their own repos and Heroku apps configured, but are sharing a database and session data.

My goal is to test key metrics on the separate apps. Currently, the way I have it setup is with a "before" filter in `application_controller.rb`. If `user.id` is even, it sends the user to beta.myapp.com.

But this method requires users to be logged in. How could I achieve this for *all* users, even if they're signed out?

Basically I want to randomize 50% of traffic to the beta version, and then persist it so the user will see the same version if they return to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your user id check with with `rand(2)`. It will be a 50% chance.

To persist this result, you can save it into a cookie, and before actually getting the random number, check if the cookie value is present:

```
   if cookies[:beta] == "true"
     # do your redirect
   else
     rand(2) == 1 ? cookies[:beta] = "true" : cookies[:beta] = "false"
     # do your redirect 
   end
```

Alternatively, add an extra field to the `User` table that would store the result, and check that.

What you're doing here is a crude example of A/B testing. You might want to look into something like [split](https://github.com/splitrb/split) or [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com) if you want to push it further.